# How do I connect a hierachical query by a substring of the prior record

Tags: sql, substring, recursive-query, connect-by, hierarchical-query

So essentially I have hierarchical data saved to a table with the standard parent/ child relationship.
I want to remove part of the child's name (for example the first letter) and use that to connect to the next level. Example: Each Parent has a child. When said Child becomes a parent they lose the first letter of their name. So "Name" becomes "ame" and "ame" is how it appears in the related records.  My code follows below.

```
SELECT LEVEL, a.Parent, a.Child, substr(a.Child,2,LENGTH(a.Child)) fixed_Child
FROM table1 a
START WITH a. = 'Name'
CONNECT BY a.Parent = PRIOR substr(a.Child,2,LENGTH(a.Child));
```

Any help would be appreciated. I can't get it to go beyond the first level.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server hierarchies? If no, is there a reason for not doing this?

Comment: It is not an option unfortunately.